# How to store the values of list in different textbox (each having different id)

Tags: hibernate, struts2

I am using struts2 and hibernate.

I have a jsp page which is loaded upon an action. The related action class returns a `list` of Objects as rows of a table stored in a database.

When the the page loads (with all the rows stored in the list), i want the data of each row and also the each of the corresponding values of columns displayed in separate textboxes, each having a different `id`. For example, the `list` has 15 objects (as rows of a table) and each object in the `list` have 10 attributes (as columns) then i want `10*15 = 150 textboxes` each with different ids.

How can i achieve this? With `<s:iterator>` and `<s:property>` i can have only 10 text boxes (which is equal to the number of columns, as we can hav only 10 no of `<s:property>`)..?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you thought about using a table or a grid control?

Comment: the table is only stored persistently on the database. The data of this table is to be displayed on the jsp page. But each cell(in above example 150 cells) is displayed in separate textboxes each text box should have a unique id. I am not using any grid control but just i need to display the data of table in textboxes instead of  cells. Can u please help me. I got realy stucked.

Comment: No not HTML table. But simply separate textboxes for each cell each with unique id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<s:iterator value="yourList" status="status">
 <s:textfield name="col1" value="%{prop1}" id="col1-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col2" value="%{prop2}" id="col2-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col3" value="%{prop3}" id="col3-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col4" value="%{prop4}" id="col4-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col5" value="%{prop5}" id="col5-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col6" value="%{prop6}" id="col6-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col7" value="%{prop7}" id="col7-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col8" value="%{prop8}" id="col8-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col9" value="%{prop9}" id="col9-%{#status.count}/>
 <s:textfield name="col10" value="%{prop10}" id="col10-%{#status.count}/>
 <br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Although, I think this is a bad design. Try using [dataTable](http://datatables.net/) or even a simple table.

Comment: thanks for your answer. By d way what will be the id of textfield 'col3' with on 2nd iterate..? (asking just get to know how will i implement as per my need)

Comment: `col3-2` I guess. Why dont you look at the generated HTML

Comment: yes i ll be arranging these textboxes in html table. thanks.. :)

Comment: Also, according to my knowledge,struts2 generates unique id's for all elements if they are inside a form.You can also try that. Put this code(remove `id` from all textfields) within a `<s:form name='dummy'>` and then check the generated HTML

Comment: Data Table is just awsum as i saw. i will surely use it.